# Highlight cell if greater than today

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to highlight cells that have a date greater than today's date.

Column H is formatted as Date.

I have the following:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    If Range("H2:H" & lrow).Value > Date Then Cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

I get a "Type Mismatch" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to @MatthieuGuindon's suggestion to @CharlesPL's answer, here's some code that does the conditional formatting. I've set it so it highlights dates that are after the day you run it as a bright yellow.

```
Option Explicit

Sub setCondFormat()
Dim lrow As Long

lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("H2:H" & lrow)
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=H2>TODAY()"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: absolutely perfect solution! Thanks again everyone!!

Answer (score 5):

`Range("H2:H" & lrow).Value` will be a 2D array (the `Value` of a `Range` is always a 2D array if more than a single cell is involved); you're getting a *type mismatch* error because you can't compare a 2D array to a `Date`; if you can't use a [conditional formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344210/1188513), you need to compare the individual array subscripts.

Last thing you want to do is to iterate each individual cells (otherwise your next question will be "how do I make this loop run faster?"). Get that array into a `Variant`, and iterate that array - since it's only 1 column, make it a 1D array with `Application.Transpose`:

```
Dim values As Variant
values = Application.Transpose(Range("H2:H" & lastRow).Value)

Dim i As Long, current As Long
For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
    current = i + 1 'array would be 1-based, so to start at row 2 we need to offset by 1
    If values(i) > Date Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(current, 8).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next
```

That way you only hit the worksheet when you *have* to.

Comment: @Deke please note that the answer you picked is the single slowest working solution. It doesn't scale, and will perform terribly given a large number of cells to iterate. Avoid hitting the worksheet as much as possible if you want performant code.

Comment: Hint to internationalization: in my local middle European setting I have to assign via `Value2`, i.e. `Application.Transpose(Range("H2:H" & lastRow).Value2)` to get correctly highlighted cells :-)

Comment: It seems that Central European date values of the local *DMY type* (as opposed to the *MDY type*) in the `values` array automatically(?) change to VarType `vbString` when assigned using `.Value`. - Solutions:  `.Value2` instead of assignment via `.Value`; otherwise you'd have to change back `values` item comparisons via `CDate()` in DMY type case). :-) @MathieuGuindon

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional formatting! As the name suggests, this is build for that!

[Microsoft blog post on date conditional formating](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/04/04/using-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-dates-in-excel/)

[image]

Comment: normally this would work well I totally agree. But the spreadsheet is constantly updated and rebuilt which would require the rule to be added everyday and I'm trying to automate a process.

Comment: @Deke conditional formatting rules can be automated too.

Comment: And then there is the strength of `Named Ranges`. Depending on how this is rebuilt, your formatting can be applied to a named range which reduces the maintenance over using explicit range addresses.

Comment: Personally, I prefer conditional formatting because of a smaller file size - `Interior.Color` applied on *single cells* can produce considerable file sizes (as this information gets multiplied for each cell) :-;

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend iterating over the range of cells and testing each cell individually. Please see below.

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("H:H")

For Each cell In rng
   If cell.Value > Date Then cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
Next cell
```